# Fresh Android studio project many errors

Tags: android, android-studio

I've wanted to learn how to build apps and I found a course online that explains what to do. for that course I downloaded java jdk and android studio and I installed everything on default settings. from there I opened up a new project with blank page, and I got like 9 errors and the preview is not working as well. all my friends are not having this problem I don't know why I am. Here's the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".Home"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://schemas.android.com/tools
http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android
http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android ">

<TextView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

The errors I get are:

"URI is no registered" (on the first 3 lines)

"Android_Width/Height/Tools is not allowed here" (thats 3 errors)

"Cannot resolve Symbol http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

"Element textview is not allowed here"

Can someone please explain and help me solve this? I want to start building and learning but I cant seem to find the problem in here.. 
Also I tried reinstalling, re opening a project, adding the uri's to the schemas % dtd list and checking if I opened the debugging xml by mistake. the file is "activity_main.xml".
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: what is path for your layout folder?

Comment: Please post your stack trace, as opposed to the separate errors.

Comment: Why you added the `xmlns:xsi` and `xsi:schemaLocation` tags? Those aren't necessary, try removing them and rebuilding your project.

Comment: The layout path is: App<src<main<res<layout
There were no errors were in my stack trace for some reason.
And I did add nothing to the project, just opened a new one and thats what I got.

Answer (score 0):

Have you declared constraint layout on app/build.gradle ?

1.Ensure you have the maven.google.com repository declared in your module-level

build.gradle file:

```
repositories {
google()
```

}

2.Add the library as a dependency in the same build.gradle file, as shown in the example below. Note that the latest version might be different than what is shown in the example:

```
dependencies {
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
}
```

3.In the toolbar or sync notification, click Sync Project with Gradle Files.

[reference](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/)

Comment: 1. I also have [jcenter()] there along with google. 2. i have [classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'] instead of what you wrote. 3. i get error of installing missing something.. i'll try to install and see if its good

Comment: That solved all but the URI errors, those were solved by martin's comment below. Thanks @touhidul-islam

Answer (score 0):

when removing all the useless clutter, it should work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

the definition of `xsi:schemaLocation` had duplicate and wrongful entries.

Comment: Thanks that solved it! but I wonder why it happened in the first place because it was a brand new project I didnt do anything to it..